# CollectionView auto height sizing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I have a CollectionView automatically set it's height based on the height of its children? All my other elements are capable of doing this.

The only "answer" I have found is to making a binding to an int that is just a static number multiplied by the number of children. This isn't a good solution though, the children can have varied heights.

Comment: What is your intention? Maybe there is a better solution to your problem than setting the height.